# Run a query on the Dynamics 365 API

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm looking for some simple boilerplate code I can use to run a query against the Dynamics 365 API and grab out some JSON.

Preferably using WebClient or HttpClient. Nothing fancy. Simplest, reusable example gets the answer.

Comment: Linking: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50795500/7920473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find example code in SDK samples. Same is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-query-data-sample-csharp).

Some key points:

1.Read the comments inside the code. Very important one:

```
/// Before building this application, you must first modify the following configuration   
/// information in the app.config file:  
///   - All deployments: Provide connection string service URL's for your organization.  
///   - CRM (online): Replace the application settings with the correct values for your    
///                 Azure app registration.
```

2.The method `ConnectToCRM` will do authentication piece & `HttpClient` call

3.Almost every single type of query including fetchxml is explained in the code sample

If you need help to get **AccessToken** from Azure registered CRM appId, then refer [Jason Lattimer blog](https://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/11/crm-web-api-using-c.html?m=1).

The overall simple boiler plate code & steps can be found in [Inogic blog](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/03/programming-using-webapi-through-c-in-dynamics-crm-2016/).

```
HttpClient httpClient= null;
httpClient = new HttpClient();
 //Default Request Headers needed to be added in the HttpClient Object
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 
 //Set the Authorization header with the Access Token received specifying the Credentials
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _result.AccessToken);
```

Comment: Am I supposed to implement the QueryData class?

Comment: @MarkMicallef that’s not a library. That’s a whole console app code with namespace, class, methods, Main to run.

Comment: I just want to hit an endpoint and get some JSON data back. Seems incredibly overcomplicated.

Comment: Where does the AccessToken in your sample code come from?

Comment: @MarkMicallef that’s why SO says too broad questions are off topic. I simply explained you in a gist from 3 blog contents (it is what it is). It is simple if you understand the background. I agree it is not simple like slack or Box web apis. But still app registration & acquiring token is same global concept.

Comment: Thanks Arun, I have been following the blog, but it has a number of problems, such as referring to non-existent methods and incorrect constructor signatures.

Comment: For example, AuthenticationContext class does not have AcquireToken() method. Closest match is AcquireTokenAsync(), which has a different sig, and uses async tasks.

Comment: @MarkMicallef :) trust internet: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gustafscrmblog/archive/2017/09/15/authenticationresult-acquiretoken-deprecated-in-adal-3-x-and-how-to-fix

Comment: Okay, thanks very much. I made some progress. I now get new error which I'm investigating: "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant authorize not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.

Comment: @MarkMicallef sounds like your tenant issue, contact Azure/O365 admins. Close this thread by accept/upvote if my answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks Arun. I am still trying to resolve the tenant authorise not found error.

Comment: @MarkMicallef I see you already have a dedicated question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645374/7920473